# Missing lanuchpad after Update on 16.04.04

Tags: 16.04

Missing launch pad and search box from desktop after update to 16.04.4 LTS. I can get a terminal up from right click. Is it possible to get these back using only the terminal.

Comment: You mean Launcher, right? The bar on the left side that has the Ubuntu button, saved apps, etc?

Comment: How did you do the update?

Comment: Software Updater and I check for Updates weekly.